# How do I mute other people on voice chat?

Tags: battlefield-4

Is there any way to mute other players on voice chat in Battlefield 4? It upsets me sometimes.

Comment: I can't check it now, as I didn't need it yet (maybe tonight, but I'm not sure). In BF3 it was possible to mute one player when you went into the main menu (ESC), show the score table and then clicked on one player.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @EricTobias windows 8.1 (64bit)

Comment: Then Kalina's way is the way to go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To mute people in Battlefield 4, simply do the following;

- Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> or press the button to bring up the game menu (on console)
- Select Team Set-up/Scoreboard
- Toggle the speaker symbol next to the player you wish to mute

This will mute the selected person/people and you will no longer be able to hear them.

Comment: Thank you but it's doesn't work for me. After click at scoreboard and click at the speaker symbol, it's not working, nothing changed.

Comment: Now it's working, I think it didn't work because of a bug.

Comment: Yeah... for some reason this wasn't working for me today but it has worked in the past. I doubt it would be a setting on the server's side. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the leaderbioard and click on the speaker

Comment: Am I missing something or is this basically a less detailed version of kalina's answer?